# ordinal response - when should we use ordinal regression?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, ordinal-data

I am running some analyses on ordinal data, with scores ranging from 0 to 5, with five indicating that a particular symptom is highly frequent and 0 its absence.

Would it be ok to use a lmer model for this? The residuals look decent, but the DHARMa plot doesn't (see below).

**Histogram of scores by condition and time**

[image: scores by condition and time]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One of the problems with a linear model is that if the probabilities are not symmetric about the mode, then things can go very badly.  Consider an extreme case where the scale is very polarizing -- everyone either answers 0 or 5.  The mean is 2.5 and yet no one chose that as an outcome.  Hence, you can miss a lot using a linear model.

Comment: This is one case where the residuals are highly misleading.  They look continuous when the DV is highly discrete.  Better to look at conditional distributions of the actual $Y$ data within subsets defined by the $X$ data.  After all, the assumption is about the conditional distributions of $Y$, and definitely *not* about the marginal distribution of the residuals.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Thank you for your comments. I just added a histogram of the data.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thank you for your comment. It is not extremely polarised, but is skewed.

Comment: The ordinal regression model will give you conditional distributions like the empirical conditional $Y$ distributions. Comparing the two gives an assessment of model fit.

Comment: @BigBendRegion I am not really sure what you mean by this. Could you give a bit more detail or point me to a resource?

Comment: Well (ahem), I do cover it in my book, "Understanding Regression Analysis:
A Conditional Distribution Approach." It includes ordinal regression as well as other discrete models, and discusses this way of assessing fit in detail.

Comment: Awesome, I will check it out! Thank you